# Is the _xml protected variable from Mage/Core/Model/Config singleton object that holds all config information from modules ?

Tags: magento

I'm studying for certification and i had this conclusion.
After magento loads all modules available from app/etc/modules/*.xml , it loads all configuration files from each one of them, and stores it on _xml property from Mage/Core/Model/Config Singleton.
Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

> The Mage_Core_Model_Config object has an _xml property. This property
>   will store a PHP SimpleXML object which represents the tree for the
>   Magento global config. However, this SimpleXML object is instantiated
>   with a custom PHP class. This class is Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element,
>   which extends a Varien_Simplexml_Element, which extends the built in
>   SimpleXMLElement.

Source: [The Magento Global Config, Revisited](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_tutorial)

You can dump config to file like this:

```
<?php

include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$config = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode();
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->write('magento_config.txt', $config->asNiceXml());
```